# Font Awesome icons not rendering

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font awesome Twitter icon by adding it inside my React Component, in my local browser it worked fine, but when I copy-pasted the same code in code pen it did not work, so any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to add font awesome as a dependency like in here
https://codepen.io/fontawesome/pen/jzNBBK
Just click `Settings -> CSS -> Add External Stylesheets/Pens`

Comment: Did not work, i still cant see my Twitter icon, here is my code pen: https://codepen.io/Rexxzar/pen/dyNdEwZ

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work with your example.

Add font-awesome as a dependency from this link (`Settings -> CSS -> Add External Stylesheets/Pens`):

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css`

Use the icons like this (font awesome new syntax [version5](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4)):

```css
  <i className="fab fa-twitter"></i>
  <i className="fab fa-tumblr fa-2x"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to add **Font Awesome** as dependency. Add `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css` it.

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

## You Just Done Following Approche:

Step 1:npm install --save font-awesome

Step 2:import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';

Step 3:
Don't forget to use className as attribute

> ```
> function yourcomponent() {
>     return <div><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin">no spinner but why</i></div>;
> }
> ```

Comment: he's trying to make it work on codepen not locally

Comment: You got it wrong, my problem is with codepen, my react app is working fine locally in my browswer.